# How can I fix this jQuery glitch so the div doesn't try to disappear when using .hover()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

What I'm trying to accomplish is make a div visible when hovering over another using the .hover() method, addClass and removeClass. But what happens is that when I hover over the added div, it reads that I'm no longer hovering over the div specified (or at least that's what I assume) in the .hover() method. This causes the div to flash on and off the screen repeatedly. How can I fix this so this problem doesn't happen? Here is the code:

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){


$('.building').hover(




    function(){

    var my_id = $(this).attr('id');

    var my_balloon ="#" + my_id + '_balloon';

    //console.log(my_balloon);

    $(my_balloon).addClass('active');

    }, 


    function(){


    var my_id = $(this).attr('id');

    var my_balloon ="#" + my_id + '_balloon';

    //console.log(my_balloon);

    $(my_balloon).removeClass('active');



    }





    );



  });
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function abc() {

         document.getElementById("Div2").style.display="";
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div onmouseover="abc()">Div1</div>
<div id="Div2" style="display:none">Div2</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the balloon overlaps the Div, it captures the event “onmouseover”.

If you don’t have to deal with it, you could use css rule to prevent any action

```
.balloon {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

This rule allows the event to pass through the balloon, as if it didn’t exist.